# Delete blank lines at end of text

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a method, that deletes empty lines at the end of a string:

```
public static String deleteBlankLinesAtEnd(String input)
{
    input = trimToEmptyString(input);
    return input.replaceFirst("\\n{2,}\\z", "");
}
```

However, it seems to also delete empty lines in the beginning of the input.

I got a little unit test:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteBlankLinesAtEnd()
{
    assertEquals("hej", TextUtils.deleteBlankLinesAtEnd("hej\n\n"));
    assertEquals("hej\nhej", TextUtils.deleteBlankLinesAtEnd("hej\nhej\n\n"));
    assertEquals("hej\n\nhej", TextUtils.deleteBlankLinesAtEnd("hej\n\nhej\n\n"));
    assertEquals("\n\nhej\n\nhej", TextUtils.deleteBlankLinesAtEnd("\n\nhej\n\nhej\n\n"));
}
```

The 3 first runs fine, the last one fails.

**Update:** Of course, the trimToEmptyString() was my problem, since it also trims the beginning..

```
public static String trimToEmptyString(String input)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return input.trim();
}
```

So everything with the regex, was working fine.

Comment: What does `trimToEmptyString()` do?

Comment: I updated the question, and that method seems to be my problem.

Comment: It was my problem. Thanks everyone! Ernest, I would like to accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex looks OK; I suspect there's a problem with `trimToEmptyString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like so:

```
public static String deleteBlankLinesAtEnd(String input)
{
    input = trimToEmptyString(input);
    return input.replaceFirst("\\n{2,}\\z$", "");
}
```

The `$` should instruct the regex to match anything just before the end of the string. In this case, it should match any new lines which are just prior to the end of the string.

Comment: This is what `\z` is already doing [see Pattern => Boundary matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). `\z` matches the end of the input.

Answer (score 1):

How about to replace all blank lines including lines full of spaces.

```
input.replaceFirst("\\n\\s+$", "\n")
```